# How can I recognize widgets at callback fucntion in kivy framework?

Tags: python

Hi guys I am learning python and kivy at the same time.

I wonder how can i recognize the component using just single function

here is my code

```
def build(self):
    btn1.bind(on_press=self.press_callback)
    btn2.bind(on_press=self.press_callback)

def press_callback(self, event):
    print self
```

I guess I can get information from self or event variable but I can't find the information of those.

Is there any document or website which introduce of that?

Comment: So you want to know which widget triggered the callback?

Comment: that's what i really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens when a function bound to `on_press` gets executed. For demonstration, I made a simple function that prints out the arguments that are passed to the function:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def press(*args):
        print(args)

    def build(self):
        self.bt = Button(on_press = self.press)
        return self.bt

TestApp().run()
```

When you press the button, this gets printed:

```
(<__main__.TestApp object at 0x02BADE30>, <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x02BADED8>)
```

So from this output we know that the callback functions receive two arguments: the app instance (which is a `self` argument) and the `Button` instance that triggered the function (which is an `event` argument in your case). The problem is that you've confused yourself with the way that you've named your variables. Name them something like `btn` and you'll know that this is the sender instance.

Summary: your trigger button is located in the `event` variable

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe self.sender?

```
def press_callback(self, event):
    print self.sender
```